# Connecting signal with lambda does not work in some cases?

Tags: python, lambda, pygtk

i'm experimenting pygtk programms development, with python 2.7, and i have a little problem when connecting signals using a lambda function :

- let us say that the class which wants to connect a signal is **the class A_Class**, and **the signal** is the string **"A_Signal"**
- we also dispose of a second **class B_class defining public function manage_signal**
- A_Class dispose of an instance **instance_b of B_class**

So, here my problem:
I don't understand why :

- if i call `connect("A_Signal", lambda <signal_parameters> : instance_b.manage_signal)` from a method of A_Class instance => we can't even enter in function manage_signal of instance_b (for example : `connect("activate", lambda menu_item :  instance_b.manage_signal)`
- if i define in A_Class a method manage_signal, which in turn call instance_b.manage_signal and call `connect("A_Signal", lambda <signal_parameters> : self.manage_signal)` => this time it works ?

Here some code to be more explicit

```
   class A_Class(gtk.Window):

       def __init__(self):
           super(gtk.Window, self).__init__()
           self.__instance_b = B_Class()
           # this does not work and i don't understand why
           self.connect("delete-event", lambda the_widget,the_event: self.__instance_b.manage_event)
           # this works
           self.connect("delete-event", self.__manage_event)

       def __manage_event(self):
           self.__instance_b.manage_event

   class B_Class(object):

        def manage_event(self):
            # do some stuffs ...
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda expression should call the handler function instead of returning it:

```
self.connect("delete-event", lambda the_widget, the_event: \
    self.__instance_b.manage_event(the_widget, the_event))
```

Of course, as you said, this is unneeded because it's equivalent to:

```
self.connect("delete-event", self.__instance_b.manage_event)
```

The lambda would only end up relaying the signal arguments to `manage_event()`, something that `connect()` can perfectly do by itself.

Comment: Thanks you very much :) In fact, i worked with a lambda because that's the common way of working in pytgk, and also i wanted to avoid passing event arguments to instance_b.manage_event. But at least, your advice works :) THanks :)